# Bootstrap 3 vertical align in div doesn't work

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried the following to vertically align text in a div ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8vw3dbd/)):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            This should not be vertically centered
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            This should be vertically centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the text remains top-aligned! What am I doing wrong?

<sub><sup>(Note: this is not a duplicate, because the duplicate questions for this issue all recommend the above as the solution: I'm asking why the solution isn't working for me).</sup></sub>

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: @sid-m ok done.

Comment: In your fiddle, there is no height declared for your div that is containing the element you wish to vertically align. How can you align it vertically if there is no padded space to adjust to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is top aligned, but unless you change the height it will look the same as middle or bottom aligned.

What you have now, but with background colors added to the divs:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="background: #bbb;">
            This should not be vertically centered
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="background: #888; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            This should be vertically centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What you will see if you give each a height of 50 pixels:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="background: #bbb; height: 50px;">
            This should not be vertically centered
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="background: #888; height: 50px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            This should be vertically centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```